# Reputation for upvotes inconsistent with upvotes

Tags: support, reputation, recent-activity, daily-reputation-limit

This is **standard daily reputation cap** question, I don't think.

Earlier this morning I answer a question and people seemed to like it.  (It's [here by the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326553/is-there-a-function-called-anytime-any-page-is-loaded-in-your-application/2326573#2326573).)  When I look at my recent activity summary, in the little green box I see the (correct) 19 upvotes, but an incorrect (I'm pretty sure) 155 reputation gained for that answer. Other than that, the only reputation I've gained today has been for one upvote for another answer from a previous day.

So, total activity for the day is (**A**) 19 upvotes for a question, and (**B**) 1 upvote for another question.  But my reputation gained is 155 rep + 10 rep = 165 rep.  There are no downvotes (by me or against me) or accepted answers or questions asked or questions accepted or bounties.  I do not believe there has been any removing of "accepted answer" or removal of upvoting for my other activity, and *certain* that there has been no such activity to explain 35 missing rep.

I am wondering why I don't have 190 rep + 10 rep = 200 rep for the two questions.  I don't care too much; I don't think my answer *that* extraordinary or anything.  Missing something about the same though bugs me.

Is there another "cap" of some sore recently added.  Or, do I misunderstand the daily reputation cap?  Cheers!

**Resolution**:  Questioner error.  I thought it was on "today" but I was on summary.  This actually **IS a standard reputation cap issue**.  Make sure you click *Today*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to click **Today**.

The summary screen for some reason doesn't show you activity from midnight (UTC) unless you click **Today**

Comment: I thought . . . that . . . was the default . . .Doh!  Yeah.  Errr, I'm not an idiot.  Really!

Comment: I *believe* the default is the activity from the *last time* you visited the site until now. Clicking `today` increases the range to the entire day (from midnight UTC).